# Closure stylesheets css renaming issue

Tags: css, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-stylesheet

[Closure Stylesheets](https://github.com/google/closure-stylesheets) can rename css classes. Example:

```
.class-one {
  // ...  
}

.class-two {
  // ...
}
```

After compilation the javascript output will be:

```
{
  'class' : 'a',
  'one' : 'b',
  'two' : 'c'
}
```

And the css output:

```
.a-b {
  // ...  
}

.a-c {
  // ...
}
```

I have a big project with many css classes. After compilation I noticed that not every word was renamed. In "a-Rf-rightslider" first two words were renamed while the last one is not.

I think that Closure Stylesheets has limitation on the renaming array size. Something like: 'a', 'b', ..., 'ZY', 'ZZ'. And skips all the rest. Am I right? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK There is no such limitation. Classnames can go way beyond ZZ and I have seen names like aScF even.

Can you make sure that the class names are used with `goog.getCssName`?

Also now days Googlers prefer to name their classes in `camelCase` instead of `joining-with-dash` because that gives you no `-`s in the minified name.